# MAAS - Deploying workstations right away

Tags: server, maas

I'm using MAAS to deploy workstations.

Because workstations don't have management tools like IPMI, I have to PXE boot the workstation for MAAS to catch it, then do it again for it to commission, and then again for it to deploy, where each time I have to go back to my desk to make these changes.

Is it possible to configure MAAS so that when it would deploy a workstation right away? Or at least make it so that I would only need to do one confirmation?

Alternatively, is there a way to set a management tool that would allow MAAS to control the workstation? This is less ideal but is still an option.

Thanks ahead!